# Find a closed formula for max$\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima, absolute-value

I would like to prove this using max$\{x_1,x_2\}=\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+\frac{|x_1-x_2|}{2}$ and by induction

So the idea here is that max $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}=max\{max\{x_1,x_2\},max\{x_2,x_3\}...max\{x_{k-1}x_k\}\}$

It's recursive and therefore is very, very messy

*Proof*

Basis (n=2): max$\{x_1,x_2\}=\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+\frac{|x_1-x_2|}{2}$ is true

Assume for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, max$\{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\}=max\{\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+\frac{|x_1-x_2|}{2},\frac{x_2+x_3}{2}+\frac{|x_2-x_3|}{2},...,\frac{x_{k-1}+x_k}{2}+\frac{|x_{k-1}-x_k|}{2}\}$ is true

Inductive: Show this holds for k+1

But... ?

---

This is where I get stuck, though. Plus I'm not even sure that my algebra is right for my "assume k" case because, while true, doesn't seem to prepare us adequately for the induction

I feel like you can't prove this without taking up a very large amount of space, since it is recursive

Comment: It is true for K=2, so assume K

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prove?  That $\max(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \max(\max(x_1, x_2), \max(x_2,x_3), \ldots, \max(x_{n-1},x_n))?$  That's not hard (without induction).

Comment: Why don't you use the simpler recursive formula $\max\{x_1, \dots, x_n\} = \max\{x_1, \max\{x_2, \dots, x_k\}\}$?

Comment: @WhatsUp, you just used the formula to prove the formula. That's circular reasoning

Comment: I'm not proving anything. I don't know what do you want to prove in the first place. I'm just pointing out that this recursive formula is simpler than yours.

Comment: @WhatsUp I'm trying to write it out in its expanded form, not just as max$\{x_1,max\{x_2,...,x_k\}\}$

Comment: Then it is still better to use this formula rather than your original one. Just recursively apply the $k = 2$ case.